# How to make Spring beans thread-safe

Tags: spring, thread-safety, code-injection, autowired

As far as I know, Spring beans are singleton by default.

What I want is make beans thread-safe considering instance attributes.
I'll try to show you using a simple example.
Consider the following code:

```
@Controller
public class MyServlet {

    @Autowired
    private HelloService service;

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void sayHello(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
        service.doStuff();
    }

}


public class HelloService {

    private int i = 1;

    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("Started " + i);
        i++;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Done " + i);
    }
}
```

The output will be something like this:

```
32911580@qtp-28064776-0 - Started 1
7802158@qtp-28064776-2 - Started 2
32911580@qtp-28064776-0 - Done 3
7802158@qtp-28064776-2 - Done 3
```

This prove the "i" var is shared between multiple threads.

I've also tryed to define the HelloService bean as prototype, like this

```
<bean id="helloService" class="my.package.HelloService" scope="prototype" />
```

but the result is the same.

The only ways I found to solve this are:
- move the declaration into doStuff() method, but it's not what I want
- make the doStuff() method, but this means have locks

What I would like is have a new instance of HelloService on every call.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

### Update

I found the solution with method injection using lookup-method.
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lookup-method-injection

Comment: That's not a realistic example. In 99% of the cases, Spring servics are stateless. Do you have a concrete realistic example of a stateful Spring service?

Comment: may be you can try declaring i as volatile. am not sure that will solve your issue.

Comment: The Spring part is irrelevant. You are asking how to make code thread safe.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have only one instance of MyServlet you will also have only one instance of HelloService.

One of the following spring scopes help:
*request*  A new instance for each HTTP request.
*session*   A new instance of the class for each new HttpSession created in a servlet container.

This will change the semantics of your code. If you declare the bean in the scope request your counter will always be 1.

To have one unique counter without locks you could use java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger.

On the other side there is nothing bad about locks. The performance impact is neglectible in most except extreme cases.

After you have built your application check it with http://vmlens.com for race conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Thomas' answer, for a service bean, request-scope is the best choice for a stateful & thread-safe component, since only one instance is normally called for in that scope.

If multiple (stateful & thread-safe) beans are needed within a particular application scope, prototype-scope would be the most appropriate choice.

Answer (score 1):

> I've also tried to define the HelloService bean as prototype, but the result is the same.

You got the same result because your `MyServlet` is singleton. So you have only one `MyServlet` instance, hence you have only one `HelloService` instance. If you make `MyServlet` as *prototype bean* as well, you will be get every time new instances for both